# Is using jQuery clever to download multiple template-files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to download and cache multiple mustache-templates and the only real way I know to do this is by downloading them via the `jQuery.ajax()`-method.

So my straightforward preload-init code looks a little ... ugly!

```
function getAllTemplatesUglyAndNotPerformant() {
  //this is no longer valid, stays just for reference; look at the bottom for the solution
  //easy - preload the template and execute it to the data
  $.ajax({
    url: 'fragments/employee.mustache',
    success: function (employeeTpl) {
      //uh-oh async process-handling forces me into digging this deeper
      $.ajax({
        url: 'fragments/employee_day.mustache',
        success: function (dayTpl) {
          //third level - now i am puzzled already
          $.ajax({
            url: 'fragments/employee_day_regular.mustache',
            success: function (protodayTplRegular) {
              //monologue: am i doing this right?
              $.ajax({
                url: 'fragments/employee_day_deleted.mustache',
                success: function (protodayTplDeleted) {
                  //most probably not
                  var cachedTemplates = {
                    employee: employeeTpl,
                    day: dayTpl,
                    protoday: {
                      regular: protodayTplRegular,
                      deleted: protodayTplDeleted
                    }
                  };
                  //shoot, i also cannot return cachedTemplates, better bury my init-method in this!
                  init(cachedTemplates);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

//initializes downloading and parsing data to what will be seen
function init(cachedTemplates) {
  //get the data
  $.ajax(
    url: '_get_data.php',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $.each(data.employees, function (iEmployee, vEmployee) {
          //this goes through a custom rendering for an employee and his sub-nodes stored in arrays (all rendered in Mustache)
          var employee = parseEmployee(vEmployee);
          var html_employee = employee.render(cachedTemplates);
          $('#data-position').append(html_employee);
        });
      }
      //ignore what may else happen for now
    }
  )
}
```

Is there a better way for downloading multiple files for caching in JS?

EDIT:
my rewrite of getAllTemplates() looks now more like this and is finally "more-understandable" and performant for the next one to touch "Peters Legacy":

```
function getAllTemplates() {
  $.when(
    $.get('fragments/employee.mustache'),
    $.get('fragments/employee_day.mustache'),
    $.get('fragments/employee_day_regular.mustache'),
    $.get('fragments/employee_day_deleted.mustache')
  )
  .done(function (employeeTpl, acquisitionTpl, protodayTplRegular, protodayTplDeleted) {
    var cachedTemplates = {
      employee: employeeTpl[0],
      acquisition: acquisitionTpl[0],
      protoday: {
        regular: protodayTplRegular[0],
        deleted: protodayTplDeleted[0]
      }
    };

    init(cachedTemplates);
  });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at promises and `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises to complete.

Comment: As for the title of the post; it's not "clever" to nest the many ajax responses... in fact it is pretty-much dissolving the benefit of async requests altogether as it is doing one-after-the-other (synchronous). Thats why `Promise.all()` and `$.when()` exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which version of jQuery you're using, so here's assuming you're using a somewhat current build;

**You can use `$.when()` which is in jQuery 1.5+.**

`$.when()` allows you to bundle (essentially) a bunch of async methods (ajax in this case) and wait until all of them have completed. In your example you are firign one request, waiting for the response and then firing another. With `$.when()`; if your connection allows it **they can all fire simultaneously**, saving a lot of time in your example!

something like:

```
$.when( 
    $.ajax( "fragments/employee.mustache" ),
    $.ajax( "fragments/employee_day.mustache" ),
    $.ajax( "..." ) 
)
.done(function( employeeRes, dayRes ) {

    // the first item in array should be the data
    var employeeTpl = employeeRes[0];
    var dayTpl = dayRes [0];

    // ...

});
```

There's loads of good examples at the [jQuery Website](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: this is delicious - you opened a whole new jQuery-dimension for me - accepted and loved!

Comment: That's a good start, but using promises would be more up to date.

Comment: @Lucero: i already read about promises and am pretty appealed to the idea... but am maintaining a programming style of someone called "Peter"... total rewrite necessary, but not imminent!
So this is actually, what Peter would have done; this is why it is called "Legacy Code" i think..

Comment: Lucero is correct that `Promise` is more future-proof. However `$.when()` works everywhere, now :) -- avoid using jQuery if you don't need it, but if you do, and are using it, `$.when()` will serve you well. It's a life-saver!